# jQueryUI Datepicker, only allow dates within ranges

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I need to implement a jQueryUI calendar that will only allow users to choose dates from certain ranges. The date ranges come in the form of an array of arrays of dates example: 
`[["2019-10-10", "2019-11-14"],["2019-09-10", "2019-09-27"]]` 
(ranges never overlap)

I have written this code but it only shows dates from one of the arrays and makes all the other unselectable.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    var allowed_dates = component.get('v.dates');
    $( "#datepickerId" ).datepicker({
            showButtonPanel: true,
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
            beforeShowDay: function(date) {
                var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
                    for (var i = 0; i < allowed_dates.length; i++) {
                        var from = new Date(allowed_dates[i][0]);
                        var to = new Date(allowed_dates[i][1]);
                        var current = new Date(string);
                        if (current >= from && current <= to) {
                            return [true, ""];
                        } else {
                            return [false, ""];
                        }
                    }
            }
        });
});
```

I think when the for loop runs for the second array the selectable dates get overridden

Comment: the problem is that you returning in for loop, that's why it only work for first range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i made following changes in your code, to achieve what you required.

```
beforeShowDay: function (date) {
    var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
    for (var i = 0; i < allowed_dates.length; i++) {
        var from = new Date(allowed_dates[i][0]);
        var to = new Date(allowed_dates[i][1]);
        var current = new Date(string);
        if (current >= from && current <= to) {
            return [true, ""];
        }
    }
    return [false, ""];
}
```

Comment: glad to see that, hope you understand the problem, that returning from else don't let   loop iterate further for next ranges.